# How to update unix-timestamp in mysql database

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I am trying to update the filed date in mysql database , this field contains unix-timestamp date.

But I do not want to convert the whole of date `1364562954` , I want to replace only the year and leave the day, month and time same.

For Example -  `19-03-2015, 03:43 PM` to `19-03-2016, 03:43 PM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to convert a Unix timestamp to MySQL's `DATETIME` format.

So for example to get a timestamp incremented by one year:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(1364562954) + INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Result: *1396098954*

For `UPDATE` it is the same:

```
UPDATE t SET tstamp= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(tstamp) + INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

**Reference: [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)**

Comment: thanks brother , but i want `update` not `select` , i try this code but it's not working `UPDATE thread SET dateline = DATE_ADD(dateline, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) where threadid = 209`